# Angular 4 HttpInterceptor : show and hide loader

Tags: angular, httpclient, interceptor, loader

I have implemented the [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#advanced-usage) interface in order to intercept the outgoing requests and the incoming responses.

I want to show a loader when a request is created and hide that loader when a response is received.

Although the code bellow works when a HttpResponse is detected, but it does not detect a Http Failure (when the response code is different than 200), therefore, the loader will not be hidden.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.loaderService.show();

    return next
        .handle(req)
        .do(event => {
            //nothing is printed when a Http failure occurs
            console.log('detecting event ', event);
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                console.log('detecting http response');
                this.loaderService.hide();
            }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: i think you need to check this one out https://github.com/mpalourdio/ng-http-loader

Comment: try or take inspiration from https://github.com/kKen94/ngx-progress

Answer (score 5):

What I recommend is simply to add a finally operator which would do the job in both success and error cases:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';

// ...

.finally(()=> this.loaderService.hide())
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding error handling with catch to the Observable next:

```
.catch((error: any) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          this.loaderService.hide();
          // show the error to the user here
        } else {
          return Observable.throw(error);
        }
 })
```

Comment: if we adjust your code to make it return an Observable anyway, it will work. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The Observable created by the .do method performs side effects for every value, error, and completion emitted by the source. In effect it spies on the original Observable and triggers these side effects when it sees something happen.

See the documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do).

You can perform your own actions as you are already doing for the value in your example by adding a handler for the error:

```
return next
    .handle(req)
    .do(event => {
        //nothing is printed when a Http failure occurs
        console.log('detecting event ', event);
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            console.log('detecting http response');
            this.loaderService.hide();
        }
    }, (err: any) => {
        console.log('... error occurred');
        this.loaderService.hide();
    });
```

There is also the completion side effect which may be of use in this scenario.